# What's the code in Highcharts such that the bars (columns) in the same group use the same color?

Tags: highcharts

[image: I want a bar chart like this]

For the life of me I couldn't figure out how to do a plot like the above in Highcharts. I also found this to be difficult to do in Excel

Comment: Does highcharts support column groups side by side? AFAIK it supports stacked columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the above by using the `colorByPoint` [option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.colorByPoint).

```
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0,
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TMAWg/).

[image]